# Git push not working-"pre-receive hook declined"?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-push

I am trying to push changes from my remote to my origin. It does not work, saying `(pre-receive hook declined` and `failed to push some refs to [repository URL]`. It also says that a file `exceeds Github's file size limit.` However, I have moved this file out of my original folder (the folder that was the remote repository) so it should not even by part of the files that are being pushed. If I do

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```

this particular file still shows it being tracked, even though it is no longer present in the original folder. I have also done `git -rm --cached` on this file, to no avail. If I do

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch [This file]'
```

it says `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes. Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.`

Comment: Run `git stash` first.

Comment: I still get 'pre-recieve hook declined' and 'failed to push some refs to [remote URL]'.

Comment: Have you run `git filter-branch`?

Comment: @ElpieKay doing that worked!

Comment: You can add answer for how you solved the problem and accept it. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.